# What does AOE on the sectional chart mean?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts

What does the AOE notation on the sectional stand for? This appears at the bottom of the information for an airport as the final line.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for ["Airport Of Entry" (see VFR Terms)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) In other words there are customs facilities there.

> All civil, private aircraft entering the U.S. must first land at an
>   airport of entry before continuing to their destinations, unless other
>   arrangements are made with U.S. CBP. Advance notification must be
>   provided electronically to CBP by means of the eAPIS. See the APIS
>   section for more information.
>   ([source](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/airspace/))

To my knowledge this is also common for international operations outside of the US/FAA jurisdiction although im not sure how its marked on various maps elsewhere.